# Python aggregate functions (e.g. sum) not working on object dtypes, but won't work when they're converted either?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm importing data from a CSV file which has text, date and numeric columns. I'm using `pandas.read_csv()` to read it in, but I'm not specifying what each column's dtype should be. Here's a cut of that csv file (apologies for the shoddy formatting).

Now these two columns (`total_imp_pma`, `char_value_aa503`)  are imported very differently. I import all the number fields and create a new dataframe called `base_varlist4`, which only contains the number columns.

When I run `base_varlist4.dtypes`, I get:

```
total_imp_pma          object
char_value_aa503      float64
```

So as you can see, `total_imp_pma` was imported as an object. The problem then means that if I run this:

```
#calculate max, and group by obs_date
output_max_temp=base_varlist4.groupby('obs_date').max(skipna=True)

#reset obs_date to be treated as a column rather than an index
output_max_temp.reset_index()

#reshape temporary output to have 2 columns corresponding to variable and value
output_max=pd.melt(output_max_temp, id_vars='obs_date', value_vars=varlist4)
```

Where `varlist4` is just my list of columns, I get the wrong max value for `total_imp_pma` but the correct max value for `char_value_aa503`.

Logically, this means I should change the object `total_imp_pma` to either a float or an integer. However, when I run:

`base_varlist4[varlist4] =  base_varlist4[varlist4].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

And then proceed to do the max value, I still get an incorrect result.

What's going on here? Why does `pandas.read_csv()` import some columns as an `object` dtype, and others as an `int64` or `float64` dtype? Why does conversion not work?

I have a theory but I'm not sure how to work around it. The only difference I see in the two columns in my source data are that `total_imp_pma` has mixed typed cells all the way down. For example, `66979` is a `General` cell, while there's a cell a little further down with a value of `1,760.60` as a `number`.

I think the mixed cell types in certain columns is causing `pandas.read_csv()` to be confused and just say "whelp, dunno what this is, import it as an object".

... how do I fix this?

***EDIT: Here's an MCVE as per the request below.***

Data in CSV is:

```
Char_Value_AA503    Total_IMP_PMA
1293    19.9
1831    0.9
    1.2
243 2,666.50
```

Code is:

```
import pandas as pd

loc = r"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
source_data_name = 'import_problem_example.csv'
reporting_date = '01Feb2018'

source_data = pd.read_csv(loc + source_data_name)
source_data.columns = source_data.columns.str.lower()

varlist4 = ["char_value_aa503","total_imp_pma"]

base_varlist4 = source_data[varlist4]
base_varlist4['obs_date'] = reporting_date

base_varlist4[varlist4] =  base_varlist4[varlist4].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

output_max_temp=base_varlist4.groupby('obs_date').max(skipna=True)

#reset obs_date to be treated as a column rather than an index
output_max_temp.reset_index()

#reshape temporary output to have 2 columns corresponding to variable and value
output_max=pd.melt(output_max_temp, id_vars='obs_date', value_vars=varlist4)


""" Test some stuff"""

source_data.dtypes
output_max
source_data.dtypes
```

As you can see, the max value of total_imp_pma comes out as `19.9`, when it should be `2666.50`.

Comment: It'd be super-helpful if we could see (a bit of) the CSV file and had an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrated the problem.

Comment: When pandas reads from the CSV it tries to infer the dtype. Columns can only have one dtype, so you can't have column of `int64` with a string in it. This would be stored as an object, the container for basically whatever. When it sees something like `1,760.60` it sees a comma and so it decides that it's not a number so it stores it as a string and gives that column `dtype=object`.  If it's simply a comma which is messing things up try adding `thousands=','` to your `pd.read_csv()` arguments and it might get it on the initial read.

Comment: Added an MCVE @AhmedFasih, as per your request.

Comment: @Aaraeus, your data dump isn't an MCVE. There are far too many rows (5 would do), some of them contain 1 number (how are we meant to know what's empty?), try `df.head(5).to_dict()` to give us something that works.

Comment: This should be better. The MCVE now has 5 rows as a data import.

Comment: Thanks, but, is your CSV file really that?! It's got no commas except as a digit separator! Maybe that's just how Pandas is printing it out, in which case, just give us the first five or so lines of the actual `import_problem_example.csv`. We'd love to have something that we can just run (with a real CSV file in place) and see what the problem is.

Comment: That was the problem - the comma as a digit separator. It looks like the `thousands=','` option that @ALollz specified has fixed the issue.